# docker container does not open port for php:latest

Tags: docker, php

I'm working with Docker containers for a while know, but I do not notice, what I am doing wrong here:

In my current folder on the host system, I have a simple `index.php` file which contains:

```
<?php echo 'hi'; ?>
```

Why is this not working?

```
docker run --name php -v $(pwd):/app -w /app -p 8080:8080 -d --rm php:cli php -S localhost:8080 -t . index.php
```

This results in an empty reply:

```
$ curl localhost:8080                                                                                                                                             
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

If I `exec` in the container and apply the `curl` there it succeeds in replying `hi`.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080`:

```
docker run --name php -v $(pwd):/app -w /app -p 8080:8080 -d --rm php:cli php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t . index.php
```

*Explanation*:

The `localhost`(or `127.0.0.1`) address is attached to the container namespace, so anything outside of this namespace cannot have access to it. Furthermore, the `0.0.0.0` (in this context) is a specific address that means *all IPv4 addresses on the local machine*. If you check inside the container, you could see:

```
$ ip a
lo:
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
eth0:
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The `eth0` interface is the interface used when you forward the port. As you don't specify the IP address of the container, you can use the `0.0.0.0` to listen on the `eth0` interface.

I don't know if I make my self clear, but you can (should) read this if you want to know more:

- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/
- https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0

Comment: Could you explain why this could help?

Comment: Thank you. Did not try it yet. But can you explain, why localhost will not work? I mean, I thought `8080:8080` will map all incomming traffic on port `8080` to `localhost`'s port `8080`.

Comment: (works, by the way)